# The row id of all items clicked in ListView returns 0, when cursor populated by Join query

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, outer-join

I have a listview on ListFragment and used CursorAdapter to provide data. CursorLoader is used for async loading from database, where LEFT OUTER JOIN sql query returns cursor. But row id is always 0 when onListItemClick() called. I am not able to get the row id of the table, corresponding to listitem clicked. How to get valid row id?

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long rowId){
//row id is always 0
}
```

join query:-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.column_name_x = table2.column_name_x)
```

Comment: Are you trying to access a value from your database by using the row id of your `ListView`?

Comment: @Razor yes that's correct. I am trying to access the db for the row corresponding to the list item. Where rowId is the row id of the item that was clicked.

Comment: You're making a huge mistake. You should never reference an item in your database by using the id in the `ListView`. The id in the `ListView` doesn't match up with the id in your database.

Comment: @Razor there is another parameter position, which is the position of the view in the list.
But id is the row id of the item that was clicked, which is row id of the cursor which was passed to the adapter contains a row called '_id' 
representing unique id for each row in the table.

documented here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getSelectedItemId()

When I use normal query(NOT join query), i got proper row id of the cursor, but id is always 0 incase of join query.

Comment: What I recommend is that you use a `HashMap<>` to store the row ids of your items in your database and use it to refernece your database when you execute queries